# how to display text fields on select the radio button

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

I have to display two different field on select of two different radio button.
i am doing it like:
 New Post
 Revision

```
<div id="title">
    <input type="text" name="title"/>
</div>

<div id="revision">
    <select name="posts">
        <option>Posts Here</option>
    </select>
</div>
<script>
$('#revision').hide();
$('#title').hide();

$('input[name="post_type"]').change(function() {
    var isRevision = $('input:checked[name="post_type"]').val() == "revision";
    $('#title').toggle(!isRevision);
    $('#revision').toggle(isRevision);
});
</script>
```

I want to apply this in my JSP but we are using taglib in our JSP. Can anybody tell me how can i implement it in my jsp. i am posting some code here.
This is the tag lib i am using to display the radio fields having to options.

```
<nok-layout:radios
path="radioPath"
options="${openerAccessOptions}"
label="Please select any one"
id="radio"
value="v1"
```

here i have taken the options of the radio in List<> and used its value as `"openerAccessOptions"` do display it.

```
List<MyOption> radioList = new ArrayList<MyOption>();
radioList.add((new MyOption("based on date","v1")));
radioList.add((new MyOption("based on months","v2")));
request.setAttribute("openerAccessOptions", radioList );
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem?You can access radio button with it's id `radio` and use your code.Using taglib is not a problem.

Comment: only hide is getting executed.